# Show metadata columns (duration tracknumberr, etc.) with Nautilus on 13.04

Tags: nautilus, 13.04, metadata

I recently updated to 13.04 and everything works smoothly but I can't seem to find a solution to show more metadata columns in *Files 3.6* (Nautilus).

On 12.10 I was able to install `nautilus-columns` to add this functionality. That doesn't seem to work anymore. Is there anything I can do on 13.04 to show the metadata columns?

I already tried downgrading Nautilus to 3.4 but that didn't work out well. I'd really appreciate it if someone could find a way to show the columns without changing the file manager installed.